# Unable to generate extent report in cucumber. I am using cucumber version 4

Tags: selenium, cucumber, selenium-extent-report

I have used extentreports-cucumber4-adapter,cucumber-java(4.2.0),cucumber-core(4.2.0),cucumber-junit(4.2.0),gherkin(2.12.2),cucumber-reporting-4.10.0,junit-3.8.1,cucumber-picocontainer-4.2.0,cucumber-extentsreport-com.vimalselvam(3.1.1)

I am able to generate execute the test cases but report is not getting generated.Do i need to give any specific path in the TestRunner file apart from this 
plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"},?

I am unable to post my pom.xml file here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with cucumber version 4.0.1 and equivalent dependencies

And extentreports 4.0.9 along with cucumber4 adapter version 1.0.7

I would suggest to use only cucumber 4 adapter in your POM.xml and not cucumber-extentsreport-com.vimalselvam(3.1.1) library

Comment: You need to have extent.properties file under src/test/resources to generate report successfully where u can actually provide the path

please refer below link for the properties to be added in that page

https://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/extentservice.html

Comment: No...adding  cucumber 4 adapter in pom.xml would do it

Comment: keep the properties file name as extent.properties under test resources folder ,adapter will do the rest

Comment: And also make sure u mark true for extent.reporter.html.start

Comment: you mark this config's as blank

extent.reporter.avent.config=
extent.reporter.bdd.config=
extent.reporter.cards.config=
extent.reporter.html.config=
extent.reporter.klov.config=
extent.reporter.logger.config=
extent.reporter.tabular.config=

Comment: remaining settings are same as in the link https://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/extentservice.html

Comment: no don't give anything out there,leave that as blank

like this {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}

Comment: in the path u mentioned in extent properties 

extent.reporter.html.out=test-output/HtmlReport/ExtentHtml.html

Comment: Can you try this sample project first and then replicate the same in yours

https://github.com/foursyth/extentreports-cucumber4-example

Comment: use junit 4.12,selenium java 3.7.0,include cucumber-jvm-deps

and am not sure the order in which plugins loaded make any difference but ordering as below can help  I guess junit->selenium->cucumber-core->cucumber-java->cucumber-jvm-deps->cucumber-junit->cucumber-picocontainer->extentreports->extentreports-cucumber-adapter

Comment: Problem resolved as I had copied extent-config and properties in some other folder.After moving files to src/main/resources ,I am able to generate the report

Answer (score 0):

This is pom.xml file
    
    
     
     org.seleniumhq.selenium
      selenium-java
      3.141.59
      
      
     
    io.cucumber
    cucumber-core
    4.0.1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>  
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>   
</dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
 <dependency>
<groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
<version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
 <dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency> 
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
<version>1.0.7</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
 <dependency>
<groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
<artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
<version>4.0.9</version>
</dependency>  
</dependencies>  
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably due to version mismatch.You can look at [this](https://github.com/Mehmetmelekk/Test_Automation_Framework_Template_For_UI_and_API_Tests.git) project, I've run it this way.
(i fixed it)